# Проблемы с запуском редактора C# в Unity3D

Tags: c#, linux, unity3d, monodevelop

Первый раз пользую Unity, установил: Linux Mint Serena 18.1 Mate, 2017.1.2f1 Personal 64. Создал проект, стратовый файл C#, но при попытке запуска редактора для его редактирования, посредством клика на иконке (а так-же команды в выпадающем меню) ничего не происходит - редактор не запускается, как внешний MonoDevelop,так и внутренний (винт секунду дрожит и замирает). Почему это может быть и как пофиксить? Отдельно MonoDevelop работает нормально.

Comment: Без логов тут не разобраться. Попробуйте запустить ваш в эмуляторе терминала, кликните на иконку и посмотрите на вывод.

Comment: Я не нахожу ничего похожего на слово "log" ни в папке редактора ни в папке проекта.

Comment: По вашему предложению запустил Unity из терминала, отработал сбойный момент, выгрузился и в терминале ничего оне увидел.

Comment: Не очень понятно из вопроса - не запускается редактор кода? редактор Unity работает?

Comment: Именно так. Отдельно - из файлбраузера редактор кода (MonoDevelop) запускается, я редактирую в нём текст, и, когда редактор Unity запускаю - тот подхватывает внесённые изменения.

Comment: А в настройках указали, что должен запускаться Monodevelop при вызове редактирования скриптов?

Comment: Да - изменил с "внутренний" на MonoDevelop. После инсталляции второго MonoDevelop-а выбора не предлагалось.

По совету с другого форума установил VSCode и заработало. Но вопрос по прежнему интересен - почему Monodevelop не заработал? 

И ещё актуальный вопрос: VSC не встроился - пришлось добавлять, но добавлять - что? Какую команду? Просто голый файл "code"? В ярлыке проставлено "code --unity-launch %F" - на что-то вероятно влияет, - на что?

Comment: Там же есть вкладка Browse и можно указать любой exe-шник. И вообще используйте встроенные, который поставляются с установщиком. Про актуальный вопрос ничего не понятно... вы его задаете или спрашиваете или что?

Comment: Xumera - вы оказались правы, - я через выбор файла выбрал файл запуска того же Monodevelop-а, что и был, и он запустился, проблема решена. Хотя непроработанность такого бага поражает.